# Breaking a long function in Python according to PEP 8

Tags: python, pep8

I read the docs, but it does not really deal with the type of functions I come across in the projects I manage. Something like this:

```
class ReallyLongChildClassName(Parent):
    def complex_function_name(self, obj=None):
        if self.condition:
            return 'bar'
        else:
            return super(ReallyLongChildClassName, self).complex_function_name(request, obj)
```

The last line clearly exceeds the 79 characters length which is specified. What is the correct way to break these type of functions? I am talking about the ones that use the `.` operator to call more functions.

I have a few different ideas, but don't really know which one is the standard way. For example:

```
class ReallyLongChildClassName(Parent):
    def complex_function_name(self, obj=None):
        if self.condition:
            return 'bar'
        else:
            return super(
                ReallyLongChildClassName,
                self
            ).complex_function_name(request, obj)
```

Comment: Start by using `super()` instead of `super(ClassName, self)`. Anyway, IMHO, the 79 char limit is outdated. Modern screens are significantly wider than terminals in the 80s so I'd say 120-150 characters on a line are not a big issue. Sure, better have shorter lines but if oyu have to use weird tricks to fit everything in 79-characters wide lines then I prefer to have a single 120-character line instead.

Comment: @Bakuriu And then again, you could have your code occupy only part of the screen, or have multiple code windows stacked, or you could want to print the code, or some developers might have need for very large font etc. None of that works if a standard width limit is not defined at least within a project, or if it is not restrictive enough. You can override the PEP-8 suggestion, which is fine, but still the 79 characters limit is the default, and there are reasons for that.

Comment: @zvone Correct. I usually code with multiple windows open, and following the 79 characters is a good way to make sure the code editor window displays everything without horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep proper indentations and line length everything is ok. There is no single, best style, you can choose it according to your taste :)

There are tools for formatting code and one I would recommend for you is Black (https://github.com/ambv/black).